# Add custom attributes to amplify federated sign in

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My question is how can add custom attributes(example: role) to amplify **federated** sign in (Facebook, google ..)
or what the logic if i want add attributes to the user after sign in is success (or add user to a group)

Comment: Any Updates on this?